# How to Play .m4a audio from url via Intent.ACTION_VIEW?

Tags: java, android, audio-streaming

I'm need to play .m4a audio file from url using `Intent.ACTION_VIEW` and it's not working, .mp3 url files will play without problems.

When I execute following codes and try to play, I see ES Media Player stopped and not being able to play the .m4a audio file.

```
Uri vidUri = Uri.parse("http://ws.stream.qqmusic.qq.com/7162036.m4a?fromtag=46");
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(vidUri, "audio/*");
context.startActivity(intent);
```

Is it impossible to play .m4a file by `Intent.ACTION_VIEW`?

Comment: Please explain, **in detail**, what "it's not working now" means. "Is it impossible play .m4a file by Intent.ACTION_VIEW?" -- there is no requirement that all Android devices have something capable of handling any arbitrary `Intent` action/`Uri` pair, if that's what you mean.

Comment: I see ESMedia Player loaded the file and it is always stopped, non-playable.

Comment: Then ask the developers of ESMedia Player what the problem is with their app.

Comment: Thanks, I think so

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to download it first the .mp4a files?
seems the ES player can not play from online media

for online stuff you can use exoplayer
https://google.github.io/ExoPlayer/

Comment: No, ES Player plays other mp3 urls very well